# JPype doesn't work inside thread?

Tags: java, python, porting

I tested out a simple hello world line to test out JPype:

jpype.java.lang.System.out.println("hello world")

It works great inside the context of a "main" python program.  However, inside the context of a running thread, I get the following response:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f5272aeb226, pid=7888, tid=139991902578432
#
# JRE version: 7.0_01-b08
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (21.1-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [_jpype.so+0x33226]  JPJavaEnv::FindClass(char const*)+0x36
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/imedia/NTsvm/src/server/nlp/hs_err_pid7888.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
Aborted
```

Answer (score 9):

citing from the [JPype documentation](http://jpype.sourceforge.net/doc/user-guide/userguide.html#python_threads):

> Python Threads
>
> For the most part, python threads based on OS level threads (i.e posix threads), will work without problem. The only thing to remember is to call `jpype.attachThreadToJVM()` in the thread body to make the JVM usable from that thread. For threads that you do not start yourself, you can call `isThreadAttachedToJVM()` to check.

HTH